# React - props.history.push moves but does not update data

Tags: reactjs

Having an issue with my React project. When I call this.props.history.push, it will move to the correct component. However, when on that new page I have to refresh the page in order for the new data to show.

I have tried messing with ComponentDidMount/ComponentWillUnMount. I also have a call to update the data in the constructor. However, it will not populate new data without a manual refresh to the page or calling the update a million times continuously in the render.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you have some logic in your new component in the constructor or `componentDidMount` and it is already mounted

Comment: But without any details or code it is hard to troubleshoot